# Is there anything I can apply to my current Cython code for speed boost?

Tags: python, cython

Just as a learning exercise I created a cython function that will take in a randomly generated squared matrix and concatenate an identity matrix. 
At 10k timed loop, the cython job completed in 6.01 microseconds whereas the Python job completes at 6.19 microseconds. I'd like to ask if there's any additional modifications I can apply to Cython for extra speed boost.

Here's my code starting with **Cython**:

```
%%cython -a
from cython.parallel import prange
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
import cython

@cython.boundscheck(False) 
@cython.wraparound(False) 
cpdef invert_gaussian(np.float64_t[:,:] matrix):

    # Declare ctypes
    cdef int m # for Identity

    # Create a inverse function using numpy array
    cdef int size = matrix.shape[1]
    cdef np.float64_t[:,:] identity =  np.zeros([size,size], dtype=np.float64)

    with nogil: 
        for m in prange(size):
            identity[m, m] = 1

    # Concatenate Result
    m_id = np.concatenate([matrix, identity], axis=1)
    return m_id
```

**Python:**

```
def join(matrix):
    size = matrix.shape[1]
    return np.concatenate([random_matrix, np.identity(size)], axis = 1)
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: ^ Eloquent answer. Thanks.

Comment: I think we generally accept "can I speed up this Cython code" questions on here as well as on codereview (they're more likely to be answered here). I don't see much to optimize here though.

Comment: Don't recommend CodeReview unless you think your own answer fits that format better.  CR is even pickier about complete runnable code.

Comment: What kind of speeds are you getting, compared to `np.eye(size)`?